# React-Native with TypeORM, babel transform error "Couldn't find program"

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I'm the maintainer of a [React-Native library](https://github.com/ospfranco/react-native-quick-sqlite). When trying to upgrade my package to the latest version of React-Native I started getting a babel transform error:

[image]

Here is a transcription of the stack:

```
LOG  Running "QuickSQLiteExample" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
error: node_modules/typeorm/browser/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js: /Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/typeorm/browser/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js: Couldn't find a Program
 ERROR  [Error: TransformError node_modules/typeorm/browser/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js: /Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/typeorm/browser/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js: Couldn't find a Program]
Error: /Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/typeorm/browser/schema-builder/RdbmsSchemaBuilder.js: Couldn't find a Program
    at Scope.getProgramParent (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:768:11)
    at Scope.crawl (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:686:32)
    at Scope.init (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:676:12)
    at NodePath.setScope (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:122:30)
    at NodePath.setContext (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:134:8)
    at NodePath.popContext (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:192:10)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:109:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:67:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:119:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at traverse (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:50:34)
    at Function.traverse.hasType (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:86:3)
    at BlockScoping.wrapClosure (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js:469:37)
    at BlockScoping.run (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js:335:12)
    at PluginPass.Loop (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js:59:38)
    at newFn (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:159:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:46:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:36:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:84:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:67:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:119:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:72:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:121:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:67:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:119:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:72:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:121:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:67:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:119:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:96:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:67:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:119:19)
    at traverseNode (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/osp/Developer/react-native-quick-sqlite/example/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:52)
```

Doing some research I found [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/13742) which seems to point to duplicated babel versions, however I already tried to de-duplicate and nothing happens.

Here is the [related issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9717) I created on the TypeORM repo but cross-posting here because I now TypeORM maintainers are flooded with work.

Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I still can't find the solution

Comment: Nope, stopped working on this months ago, tooling issue with TypeORM itself and I didn't have time to waste.

Comment: @SamuelMariña were you able to find a solution? I spent hours and cant find one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by upgrading the @babel/core package. This problem is related to babel, not TypeORM.